# Can I use a snapshot version of apache commons in my application?

Tags: apache-commons

I'm now currently using Apache Common Collections 3.2.1, in our applications.
I heard that the snapshot version 4.0 of the above has cool feature and I wish to use them.
I've seen the snapshot API, but not able to download the binaries of 4.0.

Am I making sense? Is there a way to use a snapshot version? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no maven buils available](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections), there is [no direct download](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi). What you can do is [checkout the trunk repository](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/source-repository.html) and build it yourself. It's easier than it seems.

Note that you are doing it on your responsibility and that there might be some unfinished and undocumented behvaior.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the feature you want to use?